# XML deserialization issue for XMLArrayItem

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, c#-3.0

I have to deserialize the following XML:

```
<section>
 <class_id>Cls101</class_id>
 <sect_no>1</sect_no>
 <class_section>class section</class_section>
 <meet_days>
   <day>M</day>
   <day>T</day>
   <day>W</day>
 </meet_days>
</section>
```

For which I have created the classes as below:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("section")]
public class Section
{
     [XmlElement("class_id")]
     public string ClassId { get; set; }

     [XmlElement("sect_no")]
     public string SectionNo { get; set; }

     [XmlElement("class_section")]
     public string ClassSection { get; set; }

     [XmlArray("meet_days")]
     [XmlArrayItem("day")]
     public List<Days> MeetDays { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Days
{
    [XmlElement("day")]
    public string Day { get; set; }
}
```

In the deserialized object I am getting `Day` as `null` for all 3 rows.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Day` only has one property which is a string, consider removing the `Day` class and changing the `Section` class to read:

```
[XmlArray("meet_days")]
[XmlArrayItem("day")]
public List<string> MeetDays { get; set; }
```

That way, the M, T and W values get mapped to strings rather than a string within the `Day` class.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I tried that earlier and it works. But I don't need string. I need the value to be mapped to Day property.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using [XmlArrayItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx) correctly. It designates the types allowed as items in the deserialization.

Try:

```
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(Days))]
```